# Scala: Read configuration file and store the values into a class object

Tags: scala

I am new in Scala prograaming and trying to Read Configuration file and save the values into object using Scala

My configuration file values are

```
rawIngestionTableName=rawdataingestion
enrichedDataTableName=enricheddataingestion
rulesOutputDataTableName=rulesoutput
Ip=localhost
database=abc
```

Can any one suggest me the code to do it.

Comment: What have you tried already? What didn't work? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the [TypeSafe (or Lightbend) Config library](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

It also supports Java properties (assuming that your example is a standard `.properties` file. While you're at it, I would suggest looking into the [HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#hocon-human-optimized-config-object-notation) format.

Dependency you can include is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or (if using sbt)

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is as simple as that, you can use the following:

```
import scala.io.Source

object conf extends App {

  val input = """rawIngestionTableName=rawdataingestion
enrichedDataTableName=enricheddataingestion
rulesOutputDataTableName=rulesoutput
Ip=localhost
database=abc"""

  // or if it's from the filesystem
  // val input = Source.fromFile("/path/to/file.conf").mkString("\n")

  val conf = input.split("\n").map(_.split("=", 2)).map(p => (p(0) -> p(1))).toMap

  println(conf("database")) // outputs "abc"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bjfletcher.
For me it worked with a little change. I removed the "\n" when reading from file.

```
val input = Source.fromFile("/path/to/file.conf").mkString("\n")
val conf = input.split("\n").map(_.split("=", 2)).map(p => (p(0) -> p(1))).toMap

println(conf("database"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Glad you found an answer to your problem here, but there's really no point in posting a new answer with _exactly the same code_ as the 5-year-old answer that helped you. Instead, just up-vote that answer. After you've gained sufficient reputation points you'll be able to leave a comment about dropping the `\n` when reading.